# Error adding NvidiaGpuDirverLinux extension in an Azure VM

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

I am trying to add NvidiaGpuDriverLunix extension to a VM I have created to install and run the Spatial Analysis container ([link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/spatial-analysis-container?tabs=virtual-machine))
I am using the Azure CLI to do it but I get an error.

Azure CLI:

```
az vm extension set --resource-group myResourceGroup --vm-name myVM --name NvidiaGpuDriverLinux --publisher Microsoft.HpcCompute --version 1.3
        
Error:
(VMExtensionProvisioningError) VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'NvidiaGpuDriverLinux'. Error message: "Installation failed. Exit code 0"
```

As per this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/hpccompute-gpu-linux#troubleshoot-and-support) Exit Code 0 is Operation Successful

Hope someone can help me with this error. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

After my validation, you only need to do two steps for adding the NvidiaGpuDirverLinux extension in an Azure VM.

1. Select the appropriate VM size like an NC series VM that has one K80 GPU and provision it.
2. Add the NVIDIA GPU Driver Extension [from the Azure portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/computer-vision/spatial-analysis-container?tabs=virtual-machine#set-up-the-host-computer) or use [Az cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/hpccompute-gpu-linux#azure-cli).

Make sure you have followed the correct steps in that referenced article. It works well on the NC6 size Azure VM. You also could see the installed extension from the virtual machine---settings---Extensions.

[image]